# MS Chart Tooltips appearing on random points and not in order

Tags: vb.net, mschart

I am working on MS charts with Vb.net to create a Radar chart. For each point I am adding a tooltip on the radar chart.

The same thing works when the chart type is line:

```
With pnt
    If val.Base = 0 Then
        yValue = Double.NaN
    Else
        yValue = val.Percent
        .Font = New Font("Calibri", 8.25)
    End If

    .SetValueXY(xValue, yValue)

    If val.Base > 0 Then
        .MarkerSize = 5
        .MarkerColor = cht.Series(bs).Color
        .MarkerBorderColor = cht.Series(bs).Color
        .MarkerBorderWidth = 2
        .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle
        .Label = Convert.ToString(.YValues(0))

        .ToolTip = Convert.ToString(bs & Chr(10) & se.Measure & " : " & .YValues(0) & "%") & ", Base:" & val.Base
    End If

    cht.Series(bs).Points.Add(pnt)
End With
```

However for Radar chart, either there will be no tooltip or it will appear at a random incorrect point. Meaning the first points tooltip will come up near third or fourth on the radar. I edited the output image after trying to hide the markeres, using .MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.None - 
The result is still the same.[image]

Note - These charts are generated on the runtime and added to a div control of the page. I checked using the same chart with the radar chart created in my .aspx file - and that seems to be working fine!

Edit --
I found the main reason behind this issue! I had to adjust the charts, using style="width: 100%;" to fit on the div they are created in. I tried removing the CSS of width and the tooltip align correctly! 
Is there a way to keep the CSS (otherwise the charts move out of their containers!) and adjust the tooltip to the CSS?

Comment: Please note: there are around 5 such Radar charts with each showing data for more than 3 lines and for around 10 points each. So the data sent to this page is quite huge. wanted to share this information - to know if this affects the charts in someway

Comment: This is interesting. The reason seems to be that the tooltips do not show when the mouse is over a Marker. If you remove the Markers they show fine here. If you set the `MarkerBorderWidth = 0` it also seems to work.